# "Invalid input" adding SNS topic as Lambda destination

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sns, amazon-vpc

Lambda [now supports](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-aws-lambda-destinations/) adding SNS topics (among other things) as destinations.  This can be set up via the UI.

But I can't get it to work.  I have a simple Lambda that returns a JSON that I want it to push to an SNS topic.  I open the Lambda's destination and in the destination pasted the topic.  This resulted in "Invalid input".

To get the destination to recognize the topic ARN, I first gave the Lambda SNS Full Access and then also added my Lambda role to the SNS topic Access policy.

```
"Resource": [topic arn],
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "AWS:SourceOwner": [topic owner],
          "Role": [Lambda role arn]  <---single added line
        }
      }
```

No more "Invalid input"!

Unfortunately, when I return to Lambda and go through the Destination flow again, I now get

> The provided destination config
> DestinationConfig(onSuccess=OnSuccess(destination=[topic arn]),
> onFailure=null) is invalid.

But one can only define Success or Failure (radio buttons), not both.  So presumably I mucked up permissions somewhere and the Lambda actually can't publish still.

What permissions do I need to grant the Lambda role, and how do I need to update the Topic access to make this work?

**Edit: VPCs**

I failed to mention my Lambda sits on a VPC.  Because I'm calling an external database and need a whitelisted IP, I'm using a VPC/NAT setup to keep a stable IP.

I'm not sure if this effects my situation, but from my rudimentary understanding of VPCs, I'm guessing this limits what the Lambda can directly interact with.

Comment: Same problem here; did you find a solution?

Comment: Looking back, I ended up just calling SNS directly in the lambda code

Answer (score 1):

Taking a look around, [the Asynchronous Invocation docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-async.html#invocation-async-destinations) have a section on Lambda destinations. That section seems to indicate that the only permission you need is to give is `sns:Publish` to your Lambda. Can you confirm that it does in fact receive publish permissions?

If that's not the issue, I would try taking their Cloudformation template (quoted below - from your link above) and comparing it to the Cloudformation being generated in your account when you do setup via the console.

```
Resources: 
  EventInvokeConfig:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::EventInvokeConfig
    Properties:
        FunctionName: “YourLambdaFunctionWithEventInvokeConfig”
        Qualifier: "$LATEST"
        MaximumEventAgeInSeconds: 600
        MaximumRetryAttempts: 0
        DestinationConfig:
            OnSuccess:
                Destination: “arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:123456789012:YourSNSTopicOnSuccess”
            OnFailure:
                Destination: “arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789012:function:YourLambdaFunctionOnFailure”
```

Note that from the docs, it looks like you can define `OnSuccess` and `OnFailure` *sequentially* in the console, by going through the process twice. I wouldn't quite put it past them to have e.g. an implicit requirement that both `OnSuccess` and `OnFailure` be provided.

Comment: Confirmed that my Lambda has sns:Publish.  I went overboard and granted it Allow: sns:*.
For the sequential granting, I can't save the first one, so I don't suspect I could go through the flow twice and persist any attempts.
Where would I find my Cloudformation?

Comment: You could use [Cloudformer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-using-cloudformer.html) to generate Cloudformation from existing resources, but it seems you can't get through the flow at all, or 2. try *using*  the Cloudformation above to create a Destination rule, then inspect that rule in the console to see how it turns out. Have you tried the equivalent changes to your SNS topic policy, i.e. granting more permissive access? Perhaps see [the sns policy page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-access-policy-use-cases.html)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe different to your case, but I found out the reason I was getting this error was simply because the SNS was in a different region to the lambda. Ensuring it was the same region worked as per below example. Wish the error was clearer here!

```
service: errorhandlingdemo

frameworkVersion: '2'
configValidationMode: error

plugins:
  - serverless-dotenv-plugin

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.7
  lambdaHashingVersion: 20201221
  profile: ${opt:profile, env:PROFILE}
  stage: ${opt:stage, env:STAGE}
  timeout: 5 # seconds, which is 5 seconds
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
       - sns:*
      Resource:
       - arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:540160934250:genesis-alerts

functions:
  helloworld:
    handler: handler.hello
    destinations:
      onFailure: helloFailure
  helloFailure:
    handler: failure_handler.handler
    destinations:
      onFailure: arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:540160934250:genesis-alerts
      onSuccess: arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:540160934250:genesis-alerts

custom:
  dotenv:
    basePath: ./env/
    logging: true
```